# Computing gravitational deflection of light knowing $\phi$ and $-\nabla \phi$?

Tags: gravity, photons

I have a 3D cartesian grid an in each grid I know the gravitational potential $\phi$ and the 3D gravitational field $-\nabla \phi$ (with a Newtonian approach). How to compute the path of a photon in these grids and its 3D deflection in each cell ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deflection in each cell is twice that which it would be for a Newtonian particle coming in with velocity c. You apply the transverse force to change the direction, multiplying by 2 so as to account for the GR space-space parts of the metric tensor.

This assumes that the matter making the gravity is nonrelativistic (so that you are justified in using a Newtonian potential in the first place), at low pressure (also important, like in normal matter, not neutron stars) and so the light is moving through the field effectively instantaneously. I have assumed the deflection is small, but if the deflection is *not* small from one end of the box to the other, you are probably not justified in using Newtonian gravity over the whole box.